# How are Bitcoin Addresses generated when using bitaddress.org?

Tags: wallet, address

I am trying to figure out in the the source code of bitaddress.org which files and functions that correspond to the generation of bitcoin addresses.

Link: https://github.com/pointbiz/bitaddress.org/tree/master/src

Can someone point me to which files and functions that generate the bitcoin addresses?

I would like to audit the code and also see how this all works since this can be done offline.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/pointbiz/bitaddress.org/blob/master/src/bitcoinjs-lib.eckey.js#L65 seems like a good starting point.

The functionality you are interested in has been taken from https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib, so you might want to have a look there as well.